# How do notaries provide proof to nodes that they are honest?

Tags: distributed-computing, corda, fault-tolerance, consensus

For example, how can it be proven to a node that a notary hasn't colluded with a counterparty to double spend an output?

How is trust and consensus achieved within the Corda system?

Edit:

In a scenario in which a regulatory body is the operator of a notary service, what data or information can a regulatory body reveal to a Corda node to provide a high degree of confidence in a body's integrity? (i.e. data that would provide proof or accurate evidence of the notary's ledgers' truthfulness)

Put alternatively, what data or information could reveal proof or evidence of the trustworthiness of a regulatory body?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In some cases, the trustworthiness of the notary will be beyond doubt (e.g. if the notary is run by some trusted regulatory body).

When this is not the case, you can protect against collusion by making the notary a cluster of mutually-distrusting nodes running a Byzantine Fault Tolerant consensus algorithm.

You can run a sample Byzantine Fault Tolerant notary cluster here: https://github.com/corda/corda/tree/release-V2/samples/notary-demo.

AFAIK, the only way for a notary to prove to you they are trustworthy is to observe consensus across a notary cluster of non-cooperating nodes.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I have appended an edit to my original post. Could  you provide clarification?